# Gutenberg blocks error: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, block-editor

I am learning building custom Gutenberg blocks in WordPress, Since reactjs is a new language to me, I would appreciate some help with the error below. Its a warning in the console

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See https://fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.
    in edit (created by Edit)
    in Edit (created by WithToolbarControls(Edit))
```

Below is a screenshot.

[image]

My Gutenberg javascript code is as below

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;

registerBlockType('gutenberg-mwako/section', {

    title: 'Section',

    category: 'layout',

    attributes: {},

    edit() {
        return([
            <section>
                <div className="container">
                    <h2>Title here</h2>
                </div>
            </section>
        ])
    },

    save() {
        return(
            <section>
                <div className="container">
                    <h2>Title here</h2>
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) for the `section` element in your `edit()` function (which returns an array of elements):

```js
edit() {
    return([
        <section key="my-key">
            <div className="container">
                <h2>Title here</h2>
            </div>
        </section>
    ])
},
```

Comment: PS: You can also instead set it in the inner `div` - `<div className="container" key="my-key">`

Comment: But, did you mean to return just one element like your `save()` function? Or why did you return an array in your `edit()` function? Could that be a typo? :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Also about the array, I intend to add more sections.